# Local variable in c seems to be near stack memory

Tags: c, memory, heap-memory, stack-memory

we know that local variables are in stack memory with main fuction and all other fuctions.When i print the adress of the main fuction ,the adress of a a local variable and the adress of a malloc,it seems that local variable is nearer to the malloc adress and not to the main fuction adress.Why?
code:

```
int g;

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    int l;
    printf("Adress of main fuction: %d\n", main);
    printf("Adress of a global variable(g): %d\n", &g);
    printf("Adress of a local variable(l): %d\n", &l);
    printf("malloc: %d\n", malloc(10));
}
```

Comment: Why shouldn't it be nearer ? Or further ? The compiler and the OS are free to do as they like.

Comment: And don't use `%d` for printing addresses - this is what `%p` is for.

Comment: Can you tell us those addresses?

Comment: An implementation of C is not required to have a stack at all; in fact, the word "stack" appears nowhere in the text of C99.  (It is required to support recursive function calls, but you don't need a stack to do that.)

Answer (score 2):

The exact layout of the stack, code, and data is entirely up the the compiler.

This is implementation defined behavior, so it can vary from one compiler to another.

Answer (score 1):

`auto` variables don't have to be instantiated anywhere near the code that uses them.  Given that C doesn't bounds check array accesses, that's a good thing, otherwise you could use a buffer overrun to patch binary code directly.

Here's how programs are typically (although not always) laid out in (virtual) memory:

```
              +------------------------+ 
high address  | Command line arguments |   
              | and environment vars   |  
              +------------------------+
              |         stack          |
              | - - - - - - - - - - -  |
              |           |            |
              |           V            |
              |                        |
              |           ^            |
              |           |            |
              | - - - - - - - - - - -  |
              |          heap          |
              +------------------------+
              |    global and read-    |
              |       only data        |
              +------------------------+
              |     program text       |
  low address |    (machine code)      |
              +------------------------+
```

Details vary between implementations, but that big picture is pretty common.  Machine code is segregated from data, global and read-only data is segregated from the stack and heap, etc.

Comment: The time it took to make the ASCII diagram alone is worth a point.

Answer (score 0):

No. Functions reside in different memory compared to local variables, and "global variables".

Their virtual addresses must be sufficiently different for a specific instance of process to keep different segments without overlapping addresses.

I think it's sufficiently far away to contain your stack.

```
gps@gps-HP-ProBook-4540s:~/temp/weirdtest$ ./weirdtest 
Adress of main fuction: 4195709
Adress of a global variable(g): 6295628
Adress of a local variable(l): 29174716
malloc: 17440784
```